# General questions about and to better understand programming

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ide, console, operating-system

I am new to that website and to programming, and so to Python and Linux. The thing is I do not just want to learn how to program but I also want to learn how the entire system of a computer (a computer ecosystem) works.

I have plenty of questions like how and why do you do an IDE? How do you do a terminal, console? How do you do a operating system? How do you merge two programming languages together? What is a multi-paradigm programming languages and how do you do them? Like what is a paradigm to start with?

For now those are basically my questions that I have. Maybe it isn't appropriate for your site or for certain of you but for those that they find this as not is place here, where does this belong? And yes I am clueless but everyone started clueless.

if you have any sites, or books, or even videos to where I could learn all this or diagrams that could help me anyhow; it would really be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would first start with a good Youtube video that I saw the other day about how to build your own CPU. Its a very basic CPU that doesn't have much processing power but it gives you a good idea of how the CPU in a computer operates.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cNN_tTXABUA

Then with that knowledge I would learn assembly (Opcodes) to see how the CPU computes & moves ones and zeros around the bus system.

http://www.teach-ict.com/as_as_computing/ocr/H447/F453/3_3_8/features/miniweb/index.htm

After you learn assembly you can start to see the bigger picture of how a language compiler works such as (gcc & g++).

Basically an OS (such as Linux) uses 99% C as it's primary language. Linux is a very complex system made up of many different server processes. Terminal is the name Mac OS uses and Bash is the name that Linux uses. Bash is just a program written so that the user can interact with the Kernel.